# Python IRC Bot Timing Out After 240 Seconds

Tags: python, sockets, irc, bots

I am trying to make an IRC bot, but it keeps timing out after 240 seconds. How can I fix this?

```
import socket 
host = 'test'
port = 6667
channel = '#test'
nick = "test"
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host, port))
s.send('NICK ' + str(nick) +  ' \n\r') 
s.send('USER v v v :v Script' + '\r\n')
s.send('JOIN '+channel+' \n\r')

while True:
    command = s.recv(4096)
    print command
```

Comment: The IRC server is probably getting angry at you. You're reading non-stop from their server.

Comment: You may want to try irclib. It handles all the framework for IRC (including ping). http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/
It even provides an IRC Bot example.

Comment: @Blender: that is not how sockets work - the recv call is client side only, and stalls the program if there is no data ready to be consumed already received.

Answer (score 5):

You aren't replying to ping requests from the server.

When you're idle for a long time, the server thinks the connection is dead, and sends a ping request, you need to reply with pong (and whatever the server sent to you after the ping).  So if the server sent you this, that should be your reply:

```
PING :HELLO_WORLD
PONG :HELLO_WORLD
```

Without that, the server will confirm the link is dead and terminate the connection.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using irclib- however hat is happening,most likely, is that you are not replying to the server's PING message.

Whenever a received message starts with "PING", you have to reply it with a "PONG" message containg the word PONG and your program name (and optionally host) - leaving an space after "PONG".

Check the full IRC specifcations for PING and PONG messages, and take a look onother things ou might be missing along your experiments: http://www.irchelp.org/irchelp/rfc/rfc.html

Comment: I am replying to pings but often the server isn't sending any. I'll post my own answer if I figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that I wasn't even reliably receiving PING packets from the IRC server. I fixed it by adding keepalives at the socket level:

```
    # enable keepalives at the socket (SOL_SOCKET) level
    self.client.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_KEEPALIVE, 1)
    # after 1 second of TCP inactivity, trigger keepalive pings
    self.client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPIDLE, 1)
    # send a keepalive ping every 60 seconds
    self.client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPINTVL, 60)
    # quit after 5 consecutive failures
    self.client.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_KEEPCNT, 5)
```

That, combined with sending back a PONG for each PING, is keeping my connection open longer.